# Opening multiple WindowGroups(id:for:) with same for:-value does not work

Tags: swiftui, swift-data, visionos, swiftui-windowgroup

I have been trying the seemingly extremely simple task of defining some WindowGroups in a VisionOS app with the signature `WindowGroup(id:for:)`, with unique `id`s but the same `for`-value. This should be possible according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup#Distinguish-windows-that-present-like-data). In short, my case is the following:

- I am using SwiftData to store models.
- I have a nested view hierarchy, where the user starts at Screen1, from which they can open Screen2, and from which they can open Screen3.
- I want to pass a data model created in Screen1 all the way through Screen2 and Screen3.

*Very* frustratingly, I simply cannot get this very easy setup to work: Screen1 opens just fine, the user gets to create an instance of the model there, and this model passes to Screen2 using `openWindow(id:value:)`; but Screen3 *will not even open* if I again use `openWindow(id:value:)` from Screen2.

The problem is reproduced with the minimal setup below. I am using Xcode 15.2 and am targeting VisionOS 1.0. MultipleScenes [is enabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationscenemanifest/uiapplicationsupportsmultiplescenes).

**MainApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct MainApp: App {
    private var modelContainer: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: TurtleModel.self)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(modelContainer)
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "content-view-2", for: TurtleModel.ID.self) { $turtleModelId in
            ContentView2(turtleModelId: turtleModelId)
                .modelContainer(modelContainer)
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "content-view-3", for: TurtleModel.ID.self) { $turtleModelId in
            ContentView3(turtleModelId: turtleModelId)
                .modelContainer(modelContainer)
        }
    }
}
```

**TurtleModel.swift; the data model**

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class TurtleModel {
    
    @Attribute(.unique) var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
}

extension Array where Element: TurtleModel {
    subscript(id: TurtleModel.ID?) -> TurtleModel? {
        first { $0.id == id }
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        Text("ContentView")
        
        Button("Open ContentView2") {
            let newData = TurtleModel(name: "I am a turtle")
            context.insert(newData)
            try? context.save()
            
            openWindow(id: "content-view-2", value: newData.id)
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView2.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    @Query private var turtleModels: [TurtleModel]
    
    var turtleModelId: TurtleModel.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ContentView2")
            if turtleModelId != nil {
                Text("Id: " + (turtleModels[turtleModelId]?.name ?? "none"))
                    .font(.subheadline)

                Button("Open ContentView3") {
                    openWindow(id: "content-view-3", value: turtleModelId!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView3.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView3: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    @Query private var turtleModels: [TurtleModel]
    
    var turtleModelId: TurtleModel.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("ContentView3")
            if turtleModelId != nil {
                Text("Id: " + (turtleModels[turtleModelId]?.name ?? "none"))
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I remove the `turtleModelId` attributes from the ContentViews, change the WindowGroup signature to `WindowGroup(id:)`, and navigate to them with `openWindow(id:)`, ContentView3 opens as expected; but of course, this won't give me access to the created TurtleModel. I have also tried calling `openWindow` asynchronously, to no avail.

There are no errors or even warnings in the debug output.

What is going on here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue on macOS and it seems that my fix there also works on visionOS.

What you need to do is to make the type used in the `for:` argument unique and I solved this by creating a wrapper type to hold the original id.

```
extension TurtleModel {
    struct Window3Value: Codable, Hashable {
        let id: TurtleModel.ID
    }
}
```

and then use this type in both the definition and the call for the window in SwiftUI

Declaration:

```
WindowGroup(id: "content-view-3", for: TurtleModel.Window3Value.self) { $window3Value in
    ContentView3(turtleModelId: $window3Value.wrappedValue?.id)
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
}
```

Call:

```
Button("Open ContentView3") {
    openWindow(id: "content-view-3", value: TurtleModel.Window3Value(id: turtleModelId))
}
```

Comment: I assume this is a bug of some sort and eventually it will work without this workaround.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the trick. You were right in observing the need to keep the `for:` argument unique (which indeed should not be the case, according to the docs). However, it seems to only work for me if I create a separate type for each nested window I am trying to open (`WindowValue1`, `WindowValue2`, ...); just using the one type `WindowValue` gave me the same problem. I hope this will be fixed soon.